# MongoDB custom and unique IDs

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB, and I would like to generate unique and cryptical IDs for blog posts (that will be used in restful URLS) such as *s52ruf6wst* or *xR2ru286zjI*.

What do you think is best and the more scalable way to generate these IDs ?

I was thinking of following architecture :

- a periodic (daily?) batch running to generate a lot of random and uniques IDs and insert them in a dedicated MongoDB collection with InsertIfNotPresent
- and each time I want to generate a new blog post, I take an ID from this collection and mark it as "taken" with UpdateIfCurrent atomic operation

WDYT ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is exactly why the developers of MongoDB constructed their ObjectID's (the _id) the way they did ... *to scale across nodes*, etc.

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value
>   consisting of a 4-byte timestamp
>   (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte
>   machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a
>   3-byte counter. Note that the
>   timestamp and counter fields must be
>   stored big endian unlike the rest of
>   BSON. This is because they are
>   compared byte-by-byte and we want to
>   ensure a mostly increasing order.
>   Here's the schema:

```
0123   456      78    91011
time   machine  pid   inc
```

> Traditional databases often use
>   monotonically increasing sequence
>   numbers for primary keys. In MongoDB,
>   the preferred approach is to use
>   Object IDs instead. Object IDs are
>   more synergistic with sharding and
>   distribution.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

**So I'd say just use the ObjectID's**

They are not that bad when converted to a string (these were inserted right after each other) ...

For example:

```
4d128b6ea794fc13a8000001
4d128e88a794fc13a8000002
```

They look *at first glance* to be "guessable" but they really aren't that easy to guess ...

```
4d128 b6e a794fc13a8000001
4d128 e88 a794fc13a8000002
```

And for a blog, I don't think it's that big of a deal ... we use it production all over the place.

Comment: You can also base64 encode, to have around 16 characters. Or base85 to have around 12.

Comment: Whether ObjectIds are "easy" to guess or not depends entirely on who's doing the guessing.  To a casual web browser, no, but to any hacker worth their salt these are trivial to guess.  If you need ids which are secure, please don't use ObjectIds, basewhatever-encoded or otherwise -- use something truly random like securely generated UUIDs.

Comment: If the RESTful URLs mentioned in the OP are public, then as Leopd stressed, don't use ObjectIDs. You don't ever want to expose your db keys to the world.

Comment: @Darkean: security best practice.  Don't tell the world your db keys.

Comment: @Mark, my bad, I didn't know it was a best practice. Now it is all very clear to me, thanks. I would upvote your wise reply but, you know, sarcasm.

Comment: @Tower +1 and when you use this string in an URI, ensure you use the Base64URI variant, since plain base64 contains chars which need to be escaped at URI level, which may be confusing.

Comment: +1 for ObjectID. Also note that they would be monotonic increasing values around all nodes by time, which would leverage index generation. ObjectID are IMHO a gem of MongoDB.

Comment: As long as blog post IDs are not security-relevant but you just want them to be unique regardless of sequence, you could use the **content's digest** (e.g. SHA256 or prefix thereof), which also prevents duplicates. **Neither ObjectIds nor UUIDs should be assumed to be hard to guess.** Use random octets for security-relevant data (or convert them down to your character set). From RFC 4122 on UUIDs: _Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants access)_ https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 3):

What about using UUIDs?

http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen as an example.

Comment: Your answer is greatly lacking in detail and would be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make a web service that returns a globally-unique ID so that you can have many webservers participate and know you won't hit any duplicates?

If your daily batch didn't allocate enough items? Do you run it midday?

I would implement the web-service client as a queue that can be looked at by a local process and refilled as needed (when server is slower) and could keep enough items in queue not to need to run during peak usage. Makes sense?

Comment: It does make some sense, but I'm note quite sure it's the definite answer :)If I want to ensure ID unicity, only one instance of this web service must be running, making it a real SPOF (cannot create any more blog post if down).

Comment: Well, yeah, you should only have one instance of the service running. If many, you could have a system prefix, or you could have the different systems be aware of each other and allocate in a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone who could be searching for another solution.

One way is to use simple and fast substitution cipher. (The code below is based on someone else's code -- I forgot where I took it from so cannot give proper credit.)

```
class Array
  def shuffle_with_seed!(seed)
    prng = (seed.nil?) ? Random.new() : Random.new(seed)
    size = self.size

    while size > 1
      # random index
      a = prng.rand(size)

      # last index
      b = size - 1

      # switch last element with random element
      self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a]

      # reduce size and do it again
      size = b;
    end

    self
  end

  def shuffle_with_seed(seed)
    self.dup.shuffle_with_seed!(seed)  
  end
end

class SubstitutionCipher

  def initialize(seed)
    normal = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a + [' ']
    shuffled = normal.shuffle_with_seed(seed)
    @map = normal.zip(shuffled).inject(:encrypt => {} , :decrypt => {}) do |hash,(a,b)|
      hash[:encrypt][a] = b
      hash[:decrypt][b] = a
      hash
    end
  end

  def encrypt(str)
    str.split(//).map { |char| @map[:encrypt][char] || char }.join
  end

  def decrypt(str)
    str.split(//).map { |char| @map[:decrypt][char] || char }.join
  end

end
```

You use it like this:

```
MY_SECRET_SEED = 3429824

cipher = SubstitutionCipher.new(MY_SECRET_SEED)

id = hash["_id"].to_s
encrypted_id = cipher.encrypt(id)
decrypted_id = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_id)
```

Note that it'll only encrypt a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and a space leaving other chars intact. It's sufficient for BSON ids.

Answer (score -1):

The "correct" answer, which is not really a great solution IMHO, is to generate a random ID, and then check the DB for a collision.  If it is a collision, do it again.  Repeat until you've found an unused match.  Most of the time the first will work (assuming that your generation process is sufficiently random).

It should be noted that, this process is only necessary if you are concerned about the security implications of a time-based UUID, or a counter-based ID.  Either of these will lead to "guessability", which may or may not be an issue in any given situation.  I would consider a time-based or counter-based ID to be sufficient for blog posts, though I don't know the details of your situation and reasoning.

Comment: Such a try/retry pattern would vain most of the MongoDB purpose. The main idea of MongoDB is to let the client generate the IDs, and ObjectIDs are to be used for this. Since MongoDB would be "eventually consistent", the collision check may even fail, due to synchronization reasons, on a sharded MongoDB system.

Comment: I agree that it is an unideal solution, however, publishing ObjectIDs has **many** subtle security implications.  If the client application is built poorly, it potentially has very unsubtle issues as well, though that goes to the application itself, which is somewhat beyond the scope of concern for this specific issue.  Yes, the checks may fail.  There should be something to make the IDs client-unique, however, the concept of using a time-based ID that can effortlessly be reversed, reveals information that could potentially be used against an individual or organization.

Comment: A random ID, as you propose to implement, would just NOT work with MongoDB, which is eventually consistent. So it won't be safer, since it would be broken. Security issue of the ObjectID? It is only leaking the time creation... [Not a security issue, IMHO - and I'm not the only one to say that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9452882/458259). If you need more safety at URI: 1. Encrypt the ObjectID with a private key, then serialize it as Base64 URI, would be pretty safe. 2. Use a separated URI field with a truly random GUID/UUID, as a secondary key - needs additional storage.