# Mongo ObjectIDs: Safe to use in the wild?

Tags: mongodb

I'm designing an API that interacts with MongoDB.

Now the question is, if it is **safe** to use the raw ObjectID to query for objects etc. Could any security issues arise when using the OIDs directly (e.g. in queries), or should I encrypt/decrypt them before they leave my server environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at BSON Object ID specification [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) and you will know if **it is safe for you to use**.

If you try to protect from users sending different URLs from scripts (fuskators) then it seems for me it has weak security. There won't be too many 'machine', 'pid' part combinations. 'time' part can calculated if attacker can have an idea how data was inserted (especially if using batch). 'inc' - very weak.

I won't trust ObjectIDs as the only security.

Please note there can't be a right answer to the question "is it safe" in general. You must decide yourself.

PS. But keep in mind that such URL-based security will fall to dust when users will share URLs they visited. Even best your encryption won't help.

Comment: My comment after 8 years: I won't trust you my bank account, but you can use Mongo IDs safely if you encrypt them using the algorithm known only by you. Say, instead of base64, invent base 27 with shift to 32 ;)

Comment: BTW, how did your design went? Was it a Great Success?

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't much times safer, if you don't share the object ids, because a possible attacker, which would know a possible security issue, could also use a brute force attack or something else to get the object ids.

Eventually [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072680/using-mongodb-objectid-as-a-document-id) may help you also.